# Crystal static variables

Tags: static-variables, crystal-lang

Has Crystal got static variables or must I use global variables with a file / global scope ?

```
def test(value)
  static var = 1
  var += value
  return var
end

pp test 0 #=> 1
pp test 1 #=> 2
pp test 1 #=> 3
pp test 0 #=> 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crystal has no static variables scoped to methods. You'll need to use [class variables](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/class_variables.html) for this:

```
class Test
  @@var = 1
  def self.test(value)
    @@var += value
    return @@var
  end
end

pp Test.test 0 #=> 1
pp Test.test 1 #=> 2
pp Test.test 1 #=> 3
pp Test.test 0 #=> 3
```

Also you can use macros `class_property`, `class_setter` or `class_getter`

```
class Test
  class_property var = 1
end

Test.var += 0
pp Test.var #=> 1
Test.var += 1
pp Test.var #=> 2
Test.var += 1
pp Test.var #=> 3
Test.var += 0
pp Test.var #=> 3
```